# Is it possible to render out data that has newline tokens?

Tags: reactjs, token, newline, render

Hello I have a component that renders out some data.  Some of the strings are paragraphs and I would like to have newline tokens that produce 
 html equivalent results.

Is it possible to render out a string and recongize a newline token?

I have tried placing the following tokens in the data string...

```
content: `Your \u000D \u000D \u000D \u000D \u000A\ system \u000D\u000A \r\n may not \u0009 %09 \t`
```

my render function...

```
class HelpFileContainerRender extends Component {

    render() {
        const renderHelpFile = this.props.data.filter(obj => {

            return this.props.name === obj.name;
                }).map((obj, idx) => {
                return (
                    <div key={idx}>
                        <div className="divImg">
                            <img src={`${obj.image}`} className="helpFileImg"></img>< br/>
                        </div>
                        <div>   
                            <span></span><h3 style={upperStyle}> {obj.name} </h3>
                            <span><b>Path:</b></span> {obj.path} <br /><br />
                            <span>{obj.content} </span> <br /><br />
                            <span><b>Troubleshooting:</b></span> {obj.troubleshoot} <br /><br />
                            <span><b>Video:</b></span> {obj.video} <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                {renderHelpFile}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: HTML rendering collapses white space by default, but you can override this behaviour using `white-space` CSS property, e.g. `<span style={{ whiteSpace : 'pre' }}>{ obj.content }</span>`.

Comment: White space?  Trying to insert new lines, not sure if that's the same thing